# Why do I get a segmentation fault when I try to print the getenv() output?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the problem, that I get a segmentation fault when I try to `printf` my output of `getenv`. 
I am about to learn how to handle the environment function library. 
I don't see any mistake in the code and I am totally frustrated.

Here is my code:

```
extern char **environ;

char c;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *input2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    if(input2==NULL||s==NULL)printf("malloc failed");

    printf("---------------------\n"
           "Environment-List Menu\n"
           "---------------------\n\n"
           "[1]: Print environment list\n"
           "[2]: Print environment entry (getenv)\n"
           "[3]: Add environment entry (putenv)\n"
           "[4]: Modify environment entry (setenv)\n"
           "[5]: Remove environment entry (unsetenv)\n"
           "[0]: End\n\n");


    while(1)
    {   
        char a, temp2;
        a=getchar();
        int input = atoi(&a);

        switch(input)
        {
            case 1:
                while(*environ) puts(*environ++);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Please enter the entry you're looking for and press enter:\n");
                while((temp2=getchar()!=EOF))
                {
                    printf("beginning loop\n");
                    printf("%s\n",input2);
                    printf("end of loop\n");
                }
                printf("after loop\n");
                s = getenv(input2);
                printf("getenv was called");
                printf("%c\n",*s);
                break;

            case 3:

            case 4:

            case 5:

            case 0:
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;

            default: 
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't checked the return value. If it's NULL, it'll segfault.

Comment: do you mean the return value of getenv?

Comment: Yup. Also,  `char a; a=getchar(); int input = atoi(&a);` <<<this! `atoi()` expects a nul-terminated string. Not a pointer to a single character. And you should be storing checking the return value of getchar against EOF before you store it to a `char` (and thereby truncate it).

Comment: `while((temp2=getchar()!=EOF))` add  some parentheses. (or move one `)` )

Comment: You should not be modifying the system global variable `environ`.  All else apart, it means you can't run that option repeatedly.  Use `{ char **envp = environ; while (*envp) puts(*envp++);` break; }`.  And use a higher-level input that `getchar()`; read lines and parse them.  Your numeric input leaves a newline in the buffer.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can more easily help you.  Even the currently posted code is missing several `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: OT: when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, it is better to use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: Note: the function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: regarding: `*environ++`  the order of precedence will cause this statement to yield the wrong results.  Suggest: `*(environ++)`

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `realloc`, `calloc` always check for a failure immediately,  not later after `errno` has been modified.  When outputting an error message, output it to `stderr` not `stdout`  when the error is fro a C library function,, also output the reason the system thinks the function failed. The best way to do that is to use: `perror( "your error message" );

Comment: strongly suggest replacing: `extern char **environ;

char c;` with: `extern char **environ; char **environList = environ;`  then use `environList` everywhere else.

int c;`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect, but does clutter the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: this statement: `char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);` plus this statement: `s = getenv(input2);` results in a memory leak due to the allocated memory pointer in `s` being overlayed.

Comment: The posted code has the problem that there are a number of allocated memory pointers, BUT fails to properly pass those pointers to `free()`

Comment: regarding:   printf("%c\n",*s);`  the call to `getenv()`  returns a pointer to a char string.  To print a char string use: ` printf( "%s\n", s );`

Comment: OT:  overall, several of the problems with the posted code are because the `man` pages for the called functions are either ignored or never read

Comment: thank y'all for your help!

Comment: After I considered all  your advises, the Code works properly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired operation
3. properly checks for errors

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_LINE 1024

extern char **environ;


int main( void )
{
    int done = 0;
    while( !done )
    {
        char **envList = environ;


        printf("---------------------\n"
               "Environment-List Menu\n"
               "---------------------\n\n"
               "[1]: Print environment list\n"
               "[2]: Print environment entry (getenv)\n"
               "[3]: Add environment entry (putenv)\n"
               "[4]: Modify environment entry (setenv)\n"
               "[5]: Remove environment entry (unsetenv)\n"
               "[0]: End\n\n");

        int choice = getchar();
        int ch;
        while( (ch = getchar()) && ch != '\n' );

        switch( choice )
        {
            case '1':

                while(*envList)
                {
                    puts(*envList);
                    envList++;
                }

                break;

            case '2':
                printf("Please enter the entry you're looking for and press enter:\n");
                char line[ MAX_LINE ];

                if( !fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin ) )
                {
                    perror( "fgets failed" );
                }

                else
                {
                    line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
                    if( strlen( line ) == 0 )
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    //puts( line );
                    char *temp = getenv( line );
                    if( !temp )
                    {
                        printf( "%s not found\n", line );
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        puts( temp );
                    }
                }
                break;

            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
                puts( "that option not yet implemented" );
                break;

            case '0':
                done = 1;
                break;

            default:
                puts( "invalid menu option, try again" );
                break;
        }  // end switch
    }

    return 0;
}
```